# Custom overlay in fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I would like to show an overlay with some content. I cannot touch the title here, as that will also be used. Basically, I've got a gallery of images where I do not want to call another iframe. With, inline I'll have to discreetly provide height and width (I guess), so that will stop my images from resizing accordingly.

I guess, I am clear on my requirement.

Thanks, Your help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I would like to show an overlay with some content over the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question, you could create the "custom overlay" content as (hidden) `inline` html :

```
<div id="myData">
    <div class="dataOverlay"></div>
    <div class="dataText">Lorem Ipsum blah, blah, blah</div>
</div>
```

with some style to position it :

```
#myData {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#myData .dataOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 12;
}
#myData .dataText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    z-index: 13;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

then append that (cloned) content to the `.fancybox-inner` selector using the `beforeShow` callback like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function(){
        $("#myData")
        .clone(true, true)
        .appendTo(".fancybox-inner")
        .show();
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qs2CE/)**

Comment: Exactly, this was what I wanted to do... It's just that my overlay data, would come from database, so I'll have to make some mods... I think I can carry over from here... Thank's

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.